# How to use quickfix for two symbols in char field

Tags: c#, quickfix, quickfixn

I have noticed that in Fix version 4.4 they use two symbols for a char field

Example below:

```
FIX 4.4 : MiscFeeType <139> field
Type: char
```

So lets see what values are defined for these field

https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/tagnum_139.html

```
10 = Per transaction
11 = Conversion
12 = Agent
```

But char is by definition only one character

https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/index.html#char

So when I feed fix44.xml dictionary file and generate C# code I end up with errors like

> error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

```
public const Char PER_TRANSACTION = '10';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: Change 139's type to String in your DD.

In QuickFIX/n, 139 has been generated as a StringField since 2011.  See [source](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/master/QuickFIXn/Fields/Fields.cs).